# How to create a cronjob for a python script in cpanel?

Tags: python, cron

I want to run a python script every so often on my web hosting, using cpanel, so it looks like…

[image]

However, every single formatting and file path I've tried returns with it saying no such file exists, when in fact I know for sure that it does.

Any help?

If it means anything, I'm running on shared hosting with namecheap.

Comment: shouldn't the command be `python path/to/myscript.py`?

Comment: You would think so @Fabricator , but that still gives me no such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

Your Python script might be missing permission to execute, or missing shebang on the first line to be interpreted by Python.

Easy solution is to change:

```
somepath/check_crack.py
```

into:

```
python somepath/check_crack.py
```

or even to:

```
/usr/bin/python somepath/check_crack.py
```

This way cron will know, that it shall be interpreted by Python and run it.

Comment: I have the proper shebang (#! /usr/bin/env python), and have added python to the beginning or "/usr/bin/python somepath/check_crack.py". Still I get "'/home/labtqlos/public_html/mindcracker_check.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: So you shall carefully copy paste the path not to make any character different. Make sure, no quotes are messing around. I would personally do that from command line using `crontab -e`. With an editor like `vim` you could even check if you can open the file by using `gf` (standing for "go file") and if it opens the script, you are correct, if it complains, the file is not there or yo do not have permission to see it. Check also, if you have permission to see the file.